# Trying to run Redmine on Amazon EC2 with Bitnami- what to do after launching an instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, redmine, bitnami

So I followed [these instructions](http://wiki.bitnami.org/cloud/How_to_start_a_BitNami_Machine_Image_%28AMI%29?) here to install and run Redmine on EC2 using Bitnami.

I have now the instance running and I have a public DNS. However, I cannot still figure out how to access Redmine after this?

The other thing is I got the public key from Amazon when I signed up for the EC2 service, but so far nothing has asked me for the public key. When will that be used? Do I hvae to worry about it for running Redmine?

Im looking at the AWS console and my instance has a state of "running", everything is green. Yet when I place the public DNS in the browser and click go, the browser processes the request for a long time and eventually I get the message that "Google Chrome couldnot connect to the public DNS.

Im not sure what to do or where to look for help......

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow step 4, which mentions that you need to open port 80 in your security group?  If not, it is likely the default settings are likely blocking access to the web server.

Comment: Yes, I set it up. But I might have made a mistake.How do I delete the instance and start again?

Comment: You can log in to the AWS console and delete the server from there